# Error In workflow after changing domain and Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I have changed My Sharepoint2013 Server Name And Restore in New Serve And After Restoring I have Problem With SharePoint List Workflow And its Show Me an Error About Condition Clause A thing That I Need To Mention IS Just About Windows Server 2008 To 2012 ANd As I Said Change The Server Name. Its work on OLD Server Correctly let Me Show The Workflow And Its Error In Snapshot[image]

Error [image]

if i remove If Clause It will be publish correctly !!
Can Anyone Help Me to Solve This Error?????
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the necessary authorized Types to all web applications' web.config files.

More information you can check the similar post: [Workflows - Sharepoint Designer 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3984559-ac01-4731-8d13-17b44a8245b1/workflows-sharepoint-designer-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: thanks you ,worked for me

Comment: I'm glad to help you. You can mark my post as answer if it helps. Thanks for your understanding.